# Python3: Why does an exception needs explicit conversion while printing the message

Tags: python-3.x

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.args[0]


def DoWork():
    raise MyException("My hoverboard is full of eels")
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        DoWork()
    except MyException as ex:
        print("This will get printed: " + str(ex)) #Line1
        print("This will not get printed and will raise exception: " + ex) #Line2
```

Why does an exception needs an explicit conversion in line 1. Ideally it should work as shown in Line2.
Note: I have tried both - the removal of **str** from MyException class and addition of **str**; neither of them worked.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert it to a string because `x + y` ends up calling `x.__add__(y)`, so when `x` is a string you call `str.__add__`, which operates on two strings, not on a string and an Exception. Python's built in operators and types generally don't automatically try to force things to be the right type (like javascript, for example), you have to be explicit. This is no different to having to use `int()` in `x = 1 + int("12")`, for example.

Note that if you don't want to use `str()`, you can use `%` formatting:

```
print("This will also work: %s" % ex)
```

Comment: Then why does print(ex) works? Even that uses implicit conversion.

Comment: `print()` doesn't use an implicit conversion, it takes an object as its argument (sure it ends up calling `__str__` or `__repr__` but that's not really relevant). `x + y` calls `x.__add__(y)` and when `x` is a `str`, `y` is required to be a `str` or you get an exception. If you really want `str + MyType` to just work, you can implement `__add__` and `__radd__` in `MyType` and make them work with `str` parameters, but that is horrible don't do it.